# Unable to rewrite URL in Nginx when using SSL on non-standard ports

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect

I am using a test instance of my application on non-standard ports and would like to use nginx to redirect all incoming `http` requests to `https`

Here is my nginx config:

```
I tried the above but Cant seem to get it working : please see below 

    ......
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
       listen                       9000;
       server_name                  iossapp1.com;

       if ($scheme = 'http') {
            rewrite ^               https://$server_name:9443$request_uri? permanent;
       }
    }

    ssl_certificate                 /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key             /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    server {
       listen                            9443 ssl;
       server_name                  iossapp1.com;

      error_page   497             https://$host:9443$request_uri;

       location / {
            proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:9001;
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }
    }
}
```

I have referenced the following URL but it dosent seem to help : http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,155978,213340#msg-213340

To add to the issue: the problem only surfaces when I POST a form to the server, here are a few of examples from the /var/log/nginx/access.log file  :

`127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jan/2013:17:29:14 +0800] "GET /admin/logout HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "https://iossapp1.com:9443/admin/iosIndex" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"`

`127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jan/2013:17:32:45 +0800] "POST /admin/editStaff HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "https://iossapp1.com:9443/admin/editStaff?staff.id=612" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jan/2013:17:32:45 +0800] "GET /admin/staffIndex HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"`

`127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jan/2013:17:35:45 +0800] "POST /admin/authenticate HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "https://iossapp1.com:9443/admin/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jan/2013:17:35:45 +0800] "GET /admin/masterIndex HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"`

In contrast a GET URL behaves correctly like so : 
`127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jan/2013:17:36:21 +0800] "GET /admin/masterIndex HTTP/1.1" 200 2324 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"`

I noticed the numerical value after the response code (302, 304) that is 0 when the redirect is going to be unsuccessful, in the cases where it works, the numerical value is non-zero. What does this number represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

My entry for
`proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;`

was originally missing the `$server_port`

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168155/nginx-proxy-https-to-http-on-non-standard-port

Now it works! =D