# How to run nginx SSL on non-standard port

Tags: nginx, ssl

I realize this looks like a duplicate of at least a few other questions, but I have read them each several times and am still doing something wrong.

Following are the contents of my myexample.com nginx config file located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`.

```
server {

  listen       443 ssl;
  listen       [::]:443 ssl;

  server_name myexample.com www.myexample.com;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myexample.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myexample.com/privkey.pem;

  #Configures the publicly served root directory
  #Configures the index file to be served
  root /var/www/myexample.com;
      index index.html index.htm;

}
```

It works, when I go to https://myexample.com the content is served and the connection is secure. So this config seems to be good.

Now if I change the ssl port to 9443 and reload the nginx config, the config reloads without error, but visiting https://myexample.com shows an error in the browser (This site can’t be reached / myexample.com refused to connect. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

I have tried suggestions and documentation [here](https://ma.ttias.be/force-redirect-http-https-custom-port-nginx/), [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/463628/unable-to-rewrite-url-in-nginx-when-using-ssl-on-non-standard-ports), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168155/nginx-proxy-https-to-http-on-non-standard-port) (among others) but I always get the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

I should note that I can use a non-standard port and then explicitly type that port into the URL, e.g., https://myexample.com:9443. But I don't want to do that. What I want is for a user to be able to type myexample.com into any browser and have nginx redirect to the secure connection automatically.

Again, I have no issues whatsoever when I use the standard 443 SSL port.

**Edit:** I'm using nginx/1.6.2 on debian/jessie

Comment: you mentioned that "I should note that I can use a non-standard port and then explicitly type that port into the URL, e.g., https://myexample.com:9443." Can you please explain how were you able to do this because I want to access my website using smth like "https://myexample.com:9443" with SSL included

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In order to support typing "https://myexample.com" in your browser, *and* having it handled by the `nginx` config listening on port 9443, **you will need an additional `nginx` config that still listens on port 443, since that is the IP port to which the browser connects**.

Thus:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;

  server_name myexample.com www.myexample.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myexample.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myexample.com/privkey.pem;

  # Redirect the browser to our port 9443 config
  return 301 $scheme://myexample.com:9443$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 9443 ssl;
  listen [::]:9443 ssl;

  server_name myexample.com www.myexample.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myexample.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myexample.com/privkey.pem;
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";

  #Configures the publicly served root directory
  #Configures the index file to be served
  root /var/www/myexample.com;
  index index.html index.htm;
}
```

Notice that the same certificate/key is needed for both sections, since the certificate is *usually* tied to the DNS hostname, but not necessarily the port.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the most complete answer, but what I think you're telling me is that in order to redirect to a secure connection automatically, nginx still has to be bound to port 443. Is this the case? That's the problem :-( I have another process bound to that port.

Comment: Nginx is a reverse proxy. You can have it listen on 443 and pass requests to the appropriate application.

Comment: Tim - you're correct. I probably asked a real dumb question but I was hoping there was a way to just "magically" change the SSL port.

Comment: @GojiraDeMonstah If you don't want to use port 443, you put your chosen port number in the URL. That is all.

Comment: The "ssl" was quite important. I had default_server before and struggled with it for quite sometime.

Comment: How do I do this if another web server is listening to port 443?

Answer (score 1):

When you type https://example.com, the standard for the https:// scheme is to connect to port 443. In your case, you have moved your server so that it now listens on port 9443. You get the [connection refused](https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message) message because of this - nothing is listening on port 443.

You will need to arrange to have something listen on port 443 that redirects connections to port 9443 or use a port as part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

if you change the port to a non standard one like 9443 you need to add a redirection from 443 to 9443. Set nginx to reverse proxy to that port.